# Монтирование конечных директорий в свой корень

Tags: linux, path

вот есть например такой путь:

```
/a_folder/b_folder/c_forder
```

в директории **a_folder** лежат какие нибудь файлы. Можно ли как нибудь примонтировать директорию **c_folder** в **a_folder** для того что бы туда можно было положить (в **c_folder**) файлы, а они появлялись одновременно в **a_folder** и файлы которые были в директории **a_folder** были доступны по прежнему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя.

Причина этого проста: на файловой системе не может быть файла и директории с одинаковым именем. Либо у вас файл, либо директория.

А симлинк -- это по сути, файл, пусть и специального вида.

Вы хотите совместить черты директории (содержит файлы) и симлинк (указатель на другую директорию), чтобы одна директория содержала файлы из двух разных мест. Надо либо-либо.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32852/110559

Comment: спасибо. как то не подумал что имена могут совпасть

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы намекаете на UnionFS? Можете поподробнее пояснить?

Comment: @AK, там есть варианты. какой-нибудь из них, насколько я понимаю, можно рассматривать как ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Обогнал, Александр, но всё же педантично замечу, что в рамках одного среза ФС по определению не может быть файлов с одинаковым именем в одном и том же каталоге. А накладывать слайсы можно с совершенно разным содержимым.